# Configuring CORS with NGINX and AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, cors

My app is an AWS EC2 instance, I have some problems with a CORS error.

It works great on a local server but not on a production server. My app is an angular 11 app in the frontend. Its a Spring Boot API. It is deployed in aws elastic beanstalk, I understand that aws uses nginx and this is what is generating the cors error for me

Then I tried a solution I found around: file path .ebextensions\nginx file nginx.conf

```
user                    nginx;
error_log               /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid                     /var/run/nginx.pid;
worker_processes        auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile    33282;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
  include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;

  log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

  include       conf.d/*.conf;

  map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
      default     "upgrade";
  }

  server {
      listen        80;
      server_name   dominio.com;
      root /var/app/current/public;

      location / {
        # Simple requests
        if ($request_method ~* "(GET|POST)") {
          add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"  *;
        }

        # Preflighted requests
        if ($request_method = OPTIONS ) {
          add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"  *;
          add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" "GET, POST, OPTIONS, HEAD";
          add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept";
          return 200;
        }
      }

      location /api {
          proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:5000;
          proxy_http_version  1.1;

          proxy_set_header    Connection          $connection_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header    Upgrade             $http_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
          proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      }
     

      access_log    /var/log/nginx/access.log main;

      client_header_timeout 60;
      client_max_body_size 10M;
      client_body_timeout   60;
      keepalive_timeout     60;
      gzip                  off;
      gzip_comp_level       4;

      # Include the Elastic Beanstalk generated locations
      include conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/01_static.conf;
      include conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/healthd.conf;
  }
}
```

Nginx has a configuration file by default located in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf. This file has a lot of default properties for all requests and one of these is client_max_body_size. The default value for that property is 1MB.

in the file I am updating the client_max_body_size to 10MB, but the cors error when I send a file larger than 1 MB still persists:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://dominio.com/api' from origin 'https://www.dominio.frontend.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

CORS configuration in spring:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kWlG.png)

The application works fine in production except when I use a field to add files larger than 1MB, at which point it generates the CORS error.

None of this has solved the problem. What am I missing here?

Thanks so much for any help!

Answer (score 1):

you should configure CORS in your Spring application.

1. Create a @Configuration class implementing WebMvConfigurer interface
2. Override method addCorsMappings(), like sample below, which allow all methods, all origins and apply to all API, aka: Global CORS configuration.

```
@Configuration
public class CorsConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**").allowedMethods("*");
    }
}
```

See the guide below if you want to apply selectively to specific APIs

Ref:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/

Comment: Thanks for answering, in spring I already have the cors configured the way you indicate it with WebMvcConfigurer and overriding the addCorsMappings method, edit the question and add the corresponding image to my configuration.

The application works fine in production except when I use a field to add files larger than 1MB, at which point it generates the CORS error. 
I have reviewed several forums where it is indicated that the problem is with nginx, but I cannot solve my problem. @gokien